# Dynamic form validation in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am creating a form in ionic2 in which fields changes as per categories changed by user dynamically.

> if a field category is A is selected
>
> then some fields such as start_date and time are required
>
> but for category B only start_date is required
>
> and for C both are not required.

I am using `FormBuilder` in ionic2 and validating like:

```
this.logForm = formBuilder.group({
        'start_date': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30),
                              Validators.required])],
        'time': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30),
                              Validators.required])],
    });
```

I am getting the selected category in an alert result like this:

```
category(){
   var options = {
      title: 'Choose a task category',
      inputs: [],
      message: 'Which category do you like?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Ok',
          handler: data => {}
        }
      ]
   }
}
```

In the handler of 'Ok' I can successfully retrieve the selected category.

So my question is how can i apply validation dynamically as per the category selected by user in app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [setControl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#setControl-anchor) function in the formgroup api.

For example in the data handler of category:

```
()=>{
this.logForm.setControl('start_date',new FormControl('',Validators.required);
}
```

API of formControl [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html)

Comment: Hi Suraj : I request you to please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373951/refresh-a-page-in-ionic2 . Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930623/ionic2-cancel-api-request-if-timeout .. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Suraj: can you please help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367946/array-with-custom-indexes-in-ionic2 (thanks in advance)

Comment: Hi Suraj: can you please help me in this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113604/ionic2-ion-infinite-scroller-not-working-in-iphone .. Thanks in advance