# Array with custom indexes in Ionic2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I am creating an array in a variable in Ionic2 as:

```
allMonths = {'01':'January','02':'February','03':'March','04':'April','05':'May','06':'June','07':'July','08':'August','09':'September','10':'October','11':'November','12':'December'};
```

I want to get all months **(with keys specified)** i am displaying them in html as :

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="allMonths">
        <ion-option value="{{months.key}}" *ngFor = "let months of allMonths | keys">{{months.value}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

** Although i am getting response but the issue is i am getting as:

1st: October
2nd: November
3rd: December
4th: January
.
.
.
12th: September

***** But i want them to be in series from jan to dec in popup.

Can any body suggest please where i am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually you're setting the `ngModel` to the same variable that is the *source* (array). You have to create another variable and put it in `ngModel`. Also is `keys` a `pipe`? If so, it would be better if you paste it here.

Comment: yes keys is a pipe .. with which i am accessing key's and value. Do you think that this issue is because from december the first array key is 10 here first is 1. whereas till december first of key is 0

Comment: I changed to allMonths = {'1':'January','2':'February','3':'March','4':'April','5':'May','6':'June','7':'July','8':'August','9':'September','10':'October','11':'November','12':'December'};.... now i am getting the desired response but i want that keys not like this can any one suggest how i can achieve this ?

Comment: As I said, you should paste your pipe here, so it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}

Comment: this is pipe which i am using currently. I was unable to edit question so posted here..

Comment: Your `pipe` works fine for me.

Comment: This is an object with 12 properties not an array..

Comment: @Suraj can you please help in how to create such array with such indexes in ionic2, i am unable to figure out how to create array with some custom indexes. I created allMonths = ['Jan', 'Feb','March'];,, but how to add indexes i them ?? please help

Comment: you dont hsve to add index in them if your array is ['jan','feb',...]. Read about arrays https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array  you can simply do `*ngFor = "let months of allMonths ` without keys

Comment: Yes that is correct but actually i have to pass the key of selected month in a Api request and i want it to be in the format which i have specified.

Comment: you could have a separate array of sorted keys and use that to get value from allMonths..not an ideal workaround

Comment: @Suraj: I solved it after a lot of searching. I have posted as a answer here can you have a look on it and suggest if its fine (I mean if it can be used in angular2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    After a long google I solved it as:

        allMonths:Array<Object> = [
       {id: '01', text: 'January'},
        {id: '02', text: 'February'},
        {id: '03', text: 'March'},
        {id: '04', text: 'April'},
        {id: '05', text: 'May'},
        {id: '06', text: 'June'},
        {id: '07', text: 'July'},
        {id: '08', text: 'August'},
        {id: '09', text: 'September'},
        {id: '10', text: 'October'},
        {id: '11', text: 'November'},
        {id: '12', text: 'December'},
    ];

    In Html:

<ion-item>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="allMonths">
            <ion-option value="{{months.id}}" *ngFor = "let months of allMonths ">{{months.id}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

Hope it helps someone.