# Ionic2: Ion Infinite scroller not working in iPhone

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am facing an issue with infinite scroll in Ionic 2 framework, it works perfectly for Android but for Iphone its not, any help please ...

Ionic Info:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.47
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

This is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.2.1",
"@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
"@angular/core": "2.2.1",
"@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
"@angular/http": "2.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
"@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
"ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
"ionic-native": "2.2.11",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"moment": "^2.17.1",
"mydatepicker": "^1.1.1",
"ng2-translate": "^4.0.1",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"zone.js": "0.6.26",
"sw-toolbox": "3.4.0"
},


 "devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.18",
"typescript": "2.0.6"
 },
```

- Question is this also that from where i am getting ionic-framework version 2.3.0 whereas i am giving different in package.json
- After google i found that it can be a issue of ionic version 2.3.0 and tried to downgrade it but i am unable to do so on mac. To do so i changes in package.json in ion-angular.

Please help

When i am trying npm install getting following erorr:

```
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.3.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.4.8 but none was installed.
```

npm WARN ionic-angular@2.3.0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.3.0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.3.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.3.0 requires a peer of @angular/forms@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.3.0 requires a peer of @angular/http@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.3.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.3.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.3.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-server@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.3.0 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.3.0 requires a peer of zone.js@0.7.2 but none was installed.

Comment: you are in RC4? I suggest you update

Comment: To upgrade should i change in package.json "ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-rc.4" to "ionic-angular": "^2.2.0-rc.5".

Comment: check the ionic starter app [package.json](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json)

Comment: @Suraj: I tried using that json i replaced it with my one and used npm install but it shown error that i have updated in by question. I am unable to understand from where version 2.3.0 is coming if i am using 2.0.0-rc.4. After changing in package.json and on npm install in other system i get ionic version updated in ionic info but if i am using mac then i am getting this error.

Comment: the new package.json has 2.3.0..

Comment: yes it has but i am getting version 2.3.0 even when "ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-rc.4", after updating json i a getting above mentioned error

Comment: your cli ionic info  is 2.3.0.. did you update cli recently?

Comment: no i havent ? how can i downgrade the app, also how i am getting " Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0 "  if i have given "ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-rc.4", unable to figure out this.

Comment: try `npm cache clean` once.. even your app scripts is showing different version to the app scripts in your package.json

Comment: try a fresh npm install with your original package.json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139480/discussion-between-narendra-vyas-and-suraj).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in the 3.0.1 release. However, not in the ionic 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the latest Cordova CLI is installed: (Sudo may be required)

```
npm install cordova -g
```

Ensure the ios platform has been added:

```
ionic platform ls
```

If the iOS platform is not listed, run the following command:

```
ionic platform add ios
```

If the iOS platform is installed but the version is < 4.x, run the following commands:

```
ionic platform update ios
ionic plugin save           # creates backup of existing plugins
rm -rf ./plugins            # delete plugins directory
ionic prepare               # re-install plugins compatible with 
cordova-ios 4.x
```

Install the WKWebViewPlugin:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git --save
```

Build the platform:

```
ionic prepare
```

Test the app on an iOS 9 or 10 device:

```
ionic run ios
```

An easy way to verify that WKWebView has been installed on iOS is to check if window.indexedDB exists. For example:

```
if (window.indexedDB) {
   console.log("I'm in WKWebView!"); 
} else {
   console.log("I'm in UIWebView");
}
```

Required Permissions

WKWebView may not fully launch (the deviceready event may not fire) unless if the following is included in config.xml:

config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*"/>
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```